# Basic example using React

Tags: reactjs

I'm reading [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) tutorial about React.

I try to do [this](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=0010) example. This is my code:

```js
    import React from 'react'

    export default class App extends React.Component {      

    render() {

        function tick() {
            const element = (
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (    
            setInterval(tick, 1000) 
        );

    } 
}
```

It doesn't work, I get no errors, but it doesn't do what it should.

[image]

---

The error I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `tick()` function out of the render method and the render method needs a return statement

```
      tick = () => {
          const element = (
              <div>
                 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                 <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
             </div>
          );
          return element;
       }

      render(){
          return (    
               <div>{setInterval(this.tick(), 1000)}</div>
           );
      }
```

Comment: I get: `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token   3 | export default class App extends React.Component {`

Comment: Updated my answer. Can u check now should be fine this time

Comment: Now I get that `tick is not defined`

Comment: Sorry my bad it should be this.tick() in setInterval. Check my updated answer

Comment: Ok, now I'm in the start situation, no errors but it prints only `2`.. Thanks for your patience

Comment: What do u mean by only 2?

Comment: See the first picture I post in the main message